# Why do Collections in java have int index?

Tags: java, collections

```
ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
```

and other collections in java work on `int` index.

Can't there be cases where `int` is **not enough** and there might be need for **more than** range of `int`?

**UPDATE:**
 Java 10 or some other version would have to develop new Collection framework for this. As using `long` with present Collections would **break** the **backward compatibility**. Isn't it?

Comment: That's a hell of an collection if it has more than 2,147,483,647 items.

Comment: @RobertH in theory that is possible. So my question is more of a wondering for cases when this limit might be broken. Imagine adding an element would throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` Exception.

Comment: No doubt it is - I'm just saying that it's a very large collection. My guess is that when the JVM was originally designed, such large datasets weren't even considered, however depending upon the application, and the fact that berry120 mentioned it may show up in Java 9, there seems to be a growing interest in it. I'd be curious to see what the performance will be like on such large datasets vs using a database.

Comment: @RobertH Java 10 even, my mistake. Yup, they are thinking about it in the future - there does seem to be growing interest in it although the exact details of the implementation remain fuzzy. You are correct of course that on the conception of the JVM no-one would have dreamed of such large collections, hence the original limitation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There can be in theory, but at present such large arrays (arrays with indexes outside the range of an integer) aren't supported by the JVM, and thus ArrayList doesn't support this either.

Is there a need for it? This isn't part of the question per-se, but seems to come up a lot so I'll address it anyway. The short answer is in most situations, no, but in certain ones, yes. The upper value of an `int` in Java is `2,147,483,647`, a tad over 2 billion. If this were an array of bytes we were talking about, that puts the upper limit at slightly over 2GB in terms of the amount of bytes we can store in an array. Back when Java was conceived and it wasn't unusal for a typical machine to have a thousand times less memory than that, it clearly wasn't too much of an issue - but now even a low end (desktop/laptop) machine has more memory than that, let alone a big server, so clearly it's no longer a limitation that no-one can ever reach. (Yes, we could pack the bytes into a wrapper object and make an array of those, but that's not the point we're addressing here.) If we switch to the `long` data type, then that pushes the upper limit of a byte array to well over 9.2 Exabytes (over 9 billion GB.) That puts us firmly back into "we don't need to sensibly worry about that limit" territory for at least the foreseeable future.

So, is Java making this change? One of the plans for Java 10 is due to tackle "big data" which may well include support for arrays with `long` based indexes. Obviously this is a long way off, but Oracle is at least [thinking about it](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/03/07/oracle_java_9_10_roadmap/):

> On the table for JDK 9 is a move to make the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) hypervisor-aware as well as to improve its performance, while JDK 10 could move from 32-bit to 64-bit addressable arrays for larger data sets.

You could theoretically work around this limitation by using your own collection classes which used multiple arrays to store their data, thus bypassing the implicit limit of an `int` - so it is somewhat possible if you really need this functionality now, just rather messy at present.

In terms of backwards compatibility if this feature comes in? Well you obviously couldn't just change all the `int`s to `long`s, there would need to be some more boilerplate there and, depending on implementation choices, perhaps even new collection types for these large collections (considering I doubt they'd find their way into most Java code, this may well be the best option.) Regardless, the point is that while backwards compatibility is of course a concern, there are a number of potential ways around this so it's not a show stopper by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: yes my question was more or less in the same line of thinking. that what happens when some big data applications have to be created in java.

Comment: @NarendraPathai See the edit, you'd use your own custom implementations (or find ones already out there) that made use of multiple arrays to store the data. Nothing in the standard Java libraries though.

Comment: Does scala support such  huge indexes?

Comment: @NarendraPathai I would believe not, I think it's a limitation of the VM at present (which Scala runs on.) They could potentially do some trickery to get round this but at present I don't think they do.

Comment: Wouldn't java need to develop a whole new framework for this? Merely changing the index to long will break the backward compatibility.

Comment: @NarendraPathai There would undoubtedly need to be some additional boilerplate around such a feature, yes. As to the details though, since it's really just an idea at this point no-one knows!

Comment: "but now even a low end machine has more memory than that" - no. Low end here is a typical android smartphone. Don't forget that Java is also used in embedded systems.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Fair enough if you're being picky, but I think it's pretty obvious what I was getting across!

Comment: @berry120: Yes. "2G of anything should be enough for everybody." `:-)`

Comment: Even if individual arrays were limited to two billion elements, it would still be possible for numerically-indexed collections to allow more.  Simply have `itemAt(long index)` return `items[(int)(index >> 30)][(int)(index & 0x3FFFFFFF)]`.  Further, it's already possible for some JVM implementations to use 32-bit object references to access more than 4GB of memory using address scaling, and it wouldn't be hard for a JVM to have arrays store references into an outside "large data" structure.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you are right, Collections such as Array lists supports only int values for the moment, but if you like to bypass this constraint, you may use Maps and Sets, where the Key can be anything you want, and thus, you can have as many entries as you like. But i personally think that int values are enough for structures like arrays, but if i'd like to get more, i think i would use a Derby table, a database becomes more useful in such cases .

Comment: Yes I can, but sometimes you can have needs to have such huge amounts of data in memory